I have downloaded 1 .mpd file with videos(1269)(.mp4) and audio(1897)(.mp4) data downloaded, How to play them or combine for offline use
Downloaded some data (VIDEO FILE FROM WITHIN A PC SOFTWARE)
SINGLE .mpd file
videos(1269 files)(.mp4) different folder
audios(1897 files)(.mp4)  different folder
HOW TO VIEW/CONVERT/COMBINE THESE AS VIDEO. Pardon me if I made a mistake, this is the first time that I'm Posting on this website.

DESCRIPTION:
Name    Extension   Path    Size MiB
F:\010_USE-ME\MPD
d4ad5c7d-f89b-4f50-b438-a0ba79c8b163.png    png F:\010_USE-ME\MPD\  0.09
F:\010_USE-ME\MPD\6663321c8423ab0012b7b997
master_480.mpd  mpd F:\010_USE-ME\MPD\6663321c8423ab0012b7b997\ 0.08
F:\010_USE-ME\MPD\6663321c8423ab0012b7b997\dash\
F:\010_USE-ME\MPD\6663321c8423ab0012b7b997\dash\480
1.mp4   mp4 F:\010_USE-ME\MPD\6663321c8423ab0012b7b997\dash\480\    0.17
2.mp4   mp4 F:\010_USE-ME\MPD\6663321c8423ab0012b7b997\dash\480\    0.17
upto videos(1269 files)(.mp4)
F:\010_USE-ME\MPD\6663321c8423ab0012b7b997\dash\audio
1.mp4   mp4 F:\010_USE-ME\MPD\6663321c8423ab0012b7b997\dash\audio\  0.05
2.mp4   mp4 F:\010_USE-ME\MPD\6663321c8423ab0012b7b997\dash\audio\  0.05
3.mp4   mp4
audios(1897 files)(.mp4)
